# mongodb grouping by multiple fields and counting each group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say we have a users collection with the following fields:

- age: can be either 'young' or 'old'
- company_position: can be either 'programmer', 'technician' or 'QA'
- likes_cats: boolean
- favourite_sport: can be either 'tennis', 'football' or 'none

I'd like to count how many users are old | young, like cats, like tennis or football **per company position**.

I almost got the solution:

```js
db.testing.aggregate([

    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                age: '$age',
                company_position: '$company_position',
                likes_cats: '$likes_cats',
                favourite_sport: '$favourite_sport',
            },
            total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id.company_position',
            ages: {
                $push: {
                    age: '$_id.age',
                    total: '$total',
                }
            },
            likes_cats: {
                $push: {
                    age: '$_id.likes_cats',
                    total: '$total',
                }
            },
            favourite_sport: {
                $push: {
                    age: '$_id.favourite_sport',
                    total: '$total',
                }
            },   
        }
    }
])
```

The problem with this solution is that I push repeated values into the `ages`, `likes_cats` and `favourite_sport` fields. How can I get a result like this, without repeated values inside the results arrays?

```json
{
    "job" : "technician",
    "ages" : [
        {
            "age" : "old",
            "total" : 3
        },
        {
            "age" : "young",
            "total" : 4
        },
    ],
    "likes_cats" : [
        {
            "like" : true,
            "total" : 3
        },
        {
            "like" : false,
            "total" : 1
        },
    ],
    "favourite_sport" : [
        {
            "age" : "tennis",
            "total" : 3
        },
        {
            "age" : "football",
            "total" : 4
        },      
        {
            "age" : "none",
            "total" : 4
        },
    ],
},

{ job: 'programmer', ... },
{ job: 'QA', ... },
....
```

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB, so only the mongodb 4.0 api [is partially supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-40)

Here's a link to the playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/wXpe9pqg1GV

Answer (score 0):

After going through hell and flames with sets, maps, filters and reduces, I finally came with the solution. I almost got it before, but I did not want to do the following:

```js
db.testing.aggregate([

    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                age: '$age',
                company_position: '$company_position',
                likes_cats: '$likes_cats',
                favourite_sport: '$favourite_sport',
            },
            total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id.company_position',
            ages_set: { $addToSet: '$_id.age' },
            ages: {
                $push: {
                    id: '$_id.age',
                    total: { $sum: '$total' },
                }
            },
            likes_cats_set: { $addToSet: '$_id.likes_cats' },
            likes_cats: {
                $push: {
                    id: '$_id.likes_cats',
                    total: '$total',
                }
            },
            favourite_sport_set: { $addToSet: '$_id.favourite_sport' },
            favourite_sport: {
                $push: {
                    id: '$_id.favourite_sport',
                    total: '$total',
                }
            },
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            ages: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$ages_set',
                    as: 'uniqueId',
                    in: {
                        id: '$$uniqueId',
                        total: {
                            $reduce: {
                                input: {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: '$ages',
                                        as: 'filteringValue',
                                        cond: {
                                            $eq: ['$$filteringValue.id', '$$uniqueId']
                                        },
                                    }
                                },
                                initialValue: 0,
                                in: {
                                    $sum: ['$$value', '$$this.total']
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            likes_cats: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$likes_cats_set',
                    as: 'uniqueId',
                    in: {
                        id: '$$uniqueId',
                        total: {
                            $reduce: {
                                input: {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: '$likes_cats',
                                        as: 'filteringValue',
                                        cond: {
                                            $eq: ['$$filteringValue.id', '$$uniqueId']
                                        },
                                    }
                                },
                                initialValue: 0,
                                in: {
                                    $sum: ['$$value', '$$this.total']
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            favourite_sport: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$favourite_sport_set',
                    as: 'uniqueId',
                    in: {
                        id: '$$uniqueId',
                        total: {
                            $reduce: {
                                input: {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: '$favourite_sport',
                                        as: 'filteringValue',
                                        cond: {
                                            $eq: ['$$filteringValue.id', '$$uniqueId']
                                        },
                                    }
                                },
                                initialValue: 0,
                                in: {
                                    $sum: ['$$value', '$$this.total']
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This works, it is basically applying the following algorithm in js:

```js
const test = [
    {
        id: 1,
        total: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        total: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        total: 3,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        total: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        total: 4,
    },
]

const ids = [1, 2, 3]

const result = ids.map((id) => {
    return {
        id,
        total: test
            .filter(function (value) {
                if (value.id === id) {
                    return true
                }

                return false
            })
            .reduce((curr, next) => curr + next.total, 0),
    }
})

console.log(result)
```

I'm not a big fan of this solution because there's a lot of room for error. But it works as expected.

If anyone can come up with a better solution I'd be delighted to accept as the current answer.